# How may I left-align the following as a whole?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
E&=&(ab)^{m}.\,\text{(Hypothesis).}
\\
&=&(ab)\times (ab)\times (ab)\times \dotsm m\,\text{factors}.\,\text{(Definition of an index).}
\\
&=&(a\times a\times a\times \dotsm m\,\text{factors}\times \\
&&(b\times b\times b\times \dotsm m\,\text{factors}.\,\text{(Laws of association and commutation).}
\\
E&=&a^{m}\times b^{m}.\,\text{(Definition of an index).}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the AMS alignments, since you are loading the package anyway:

[image]

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
E&=(ab)^{m}.\,\text{(Hypothesis).}
\\
&=(ab)\times (ab)\times (ab)\times \dotsm m\,\text{factors}.\,\text{(Definition of an index).}
\\
&=(a\times a\times a\times \dotsm m\,\text{factors}\times \\
&(b\times b\times b\times \dotsm m\,\text{factors}.\,\text{(Laws of association and commutation).}
\\
E&=a^{m}\times b^{m}.\,\text{(Definition of an index).}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Or perhaps

[image]

```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
E&=(ab)^{m}\tag{Hypothesis}
\\[\jot]
&=\underbrace{(ab)\times (ab)\times (ab)\times \dotsm}_{m\,\text{factors}}\tag{Definition of an index}
\\[\jot]
&=\underbrace{( a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{ m\,\text{factors}}\times 
\underbrace{(b\times b\times \dotsm)}_{ m\,\text{factors}}\tag{Laws of association and commutation}
\\[\jot]
&=a^{m}\times b^{m}\tag{Definition of an index}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To David,
I have been waiting for an answer to proceed with my work. I shall be so grateful to you for providing me an answer. This works perfectly for me. :)

Comment: hmmm.  the `\times` after `\text` doesn't have the correct spacing, but maybe because there's nothing after it.  and there are a couple of unmatched left parens (although that was also the case in the original.  and, finally, i think that the fourth line should be indented to the right of the equals sign; in the original it was lined up *after* the equals. (double `&&` on the line after `&=&`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton sorry, I'll sit at the back of the class, will edit;-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton better?

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa see updated answer

Comment: oh, that's very nice indeed!  (you did go a little beyond what was asked.  then again, i did rather needle you about the limitations of the previous.)  well done!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle,
The above set up looks so delicate than that of the previous set up. What this improvement taught me was how to align each logical course of reasoning with one another. I had to break the third mathematical statement, because I had not enough space to write the reason within brackets; underbrace environment saves much space for me to write it. Thank you very much, David!

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa you should thank barabara (she knows something about proof reading math expressions:-)